# It is possible to pass parameter to component in the routes

Tags: angular

I would like have the same one component for different paths with different parameters. Something like this:

```ts
export const appRoutes:Routes = [
  { path: 'rss', component: RssComponent(1) },
  { path: 'vk', component: RssComponent(2) }
];
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass constructor parameters, but you can pass `data`

```ts
export const appRoutes:Routes = [
  { path: 'rss', component: RssComponent, data: {id: 1} },
  { path: 'vk', component: RssComponent, data: {id: 2} }
];
```

```ts
class RssComponent {
  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) {
    route.data.subscribe(d => {
      console.log('Route data id:', d);
    }
  }
}
```